# How can I call image from global js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5.3, global

My global js here :

> ...\htdocs\mysystem\public\js\main.js

The code like this :

```
$(function(){
    ...
    $('#loading').html('<img class="displayed" src="{{asset("img/loading.gif")}}">');
    ...
```

I put the image here :

> ...\htdocs\mysystem\public\img\loading.gif

When executes, it not success call the image and no error

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: 1: Check `F12` Developer console in the browser![network tab]  2: if you have a real `js` file i dont thing you can parse data via `{{ }}` into it. Is this smarty or twig? if the `$('#loading').h` line is in the html part of your page, then check source code for the correct url was parsed into it.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions, So what is the solution?

Comment: Thing i gave many tips. Did you check all, did you detect a bug/issue that you can show. i can only make assumptions here :-)

Comment: .js files don't run PHP and therefore don't render blade templated files.  Just use `src="/img/loading.gif"` it should be enough.

Comment: @apokryfos, It's the same. It not display the image

Answer (score 0):

Correct the path to the image like this:

```js
$(function(){
    ...
    $('#loading').html('<img class="displayed" src="../img/loading.gif">');
    ...
```

Update:
Are the parsers necessary? Within the provided context it is not clear whether you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, if not worked then let me know the error/cause.

```
var imagePath = '{{asset("img/loading.gif")}}';
$('#loading').html('<img class="displayed" src="'+imagePath+'">');
```

Comment: I need you help. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780749/how-can-i-make-sub-query-in-laravel-eloquent